# How to Get element using dynamic generated control id in asp,net

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a check box list with dynamically generated id using category ids.

how can i get those element using ids.

i added this code behind.

now i need to get it through JavaScript using client id

i am using asp.net 3.5

```
 var clientid="subcat_"+id+".ClientID"
var tabl=$find( "<%="+clientid+" %>")

var  tbl = document.getElementById(tabl)
```

is there any possible way to do it

Comment: Can you please give some more input in code behind?

Comment: Dim chkpanel As Panel = e.Item.FindControl("panlsubcat")
        Dim cb2 As CheckBoxList = New CheckBoxList
        cb2.ID = "subcat_" & CategoryID.Value
        chkpanel.Controls.Add(cb2)

i added id  like above code

Comment: i added like above code